# iOS Xcode: Editing Root View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

## How to edit Root View Controller

Hello every one, I'm going crazy trying to find out how to switch a root controller with a table view inside, for a root controller with a normal view.

[image]

As you can see from the image I have the navigation controller pointing to a root view controller with a table view. Well I want that my navigation controller points to a root controller designed like the view controller in the right side.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why is there a view controller before the navigation controller?

Comment: it's a view controller that will shows up the logo of the app, it is a wrong design?

Comment: @TheMiotz Yes. The splash screen VC should be located in its own storyboard file. It should have been created by xcode for you. It's the one shown while loading the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head: Select the segue to the unwanted VC. Delete it. Ctrl-drag to the wanted controller from the navigation controller and set it as root.

Comment: I've tried, but i'll see a black screen doing that.

Comment: are you so kind to tell me, why, in the next controllers I can't see the arrow back into the navigation bar?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by _next controllers_. If you only have a root VC then there is nothing to go back to.

Comment: I've edited the picture, so you can understand. My problem is that when I press the button on the second view controller I see a black screen, and there is not a back arrow into the nav bar

Comment: Delete the 2nd and 3rd navigation controller. You only need one controller to control your navigation. A navigation controller is like a stack of cards. You don't need three stacks.

Comment: That is better taught by a storyboard tutorial than on Stackoverflow. Read up on the different types and why they exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the initial controller as navigation control, else you can not navigate from view controller as you did in your story board.

So select your view controller where a button is there(The left most in the story board). Then you can navigate to the screen.

So Your flow would be

1. Navigation controller (Make it Initial controller)
2. Connect the next view controller as root controller.

Then any controller you want can choose show/present type segue.

Hope it helps.